# Outlook 2010 Outbox is Missing

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I can't see the Outbox folder in Outlook 2010, how do I make it visible?

Also, it would be useful to be able to delete a message, if I decide not to send it and I have a two minute delay after pressing the Send button.

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1 should fix your hidden folder issue.**

Follow these steps to reset the views:

1. Click on Start ->All Programs.
2. Go to Accessories -> Click on RUN.
3. Type Outlook /cleanviews (leave a space after Outlook) -> Click OK.

Method 2:
Remove and re-add the e-mail accounts in Outlook. Refer to the following link:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/add-or-remove-an-email-account-HA010354414.aspx

If that does not work, create a new profile in Outlook. Refer the article on how to create a new profile:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/829918

**To delay the sending of your messages:**

When you’re in the message, and before you hit Send (and that’s critical, of course), on the Options tab within More Options, you’ll find this “Delay Delivery” button:[image: Here is the Delay Delivery Button]